# HTML5: Image rotating around pivot, wrong orientation

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, orientation, pivot

I want to create an animation which is drawned on a following diagram on the left. It should visualize i.e. clouds spinning around sphere.

[image: Wrong rotation around a pivot]

I want the cloud A to spin around the pivot point X in some fixed radius (i.e. 100px). Of course, it is essention for the cloud to get properly oriented, otherwise it would look weird. I have achieved the effect of rotation around the pivot in the fixed distance, but my rectange was wrongly oriented (see the figure on the right).

The code is following:

```
<canvas id="cloudsCanvas" width="1050" height="300"></canvas>
   <script>
        var cloudCenter = [400, 400];

        // pivot point coordinates
        var cx = 1050 / 2;
        var cy = 800;
        var deg = 45;

        var cloud1 = new Image;


        window.onload = function () {
            var cloudsCanvas = document.getElementById("cloudsCanvas");
            var cloudsContext = cloudsCanvas.getContext("2d");

            setInterval(function () {
                cloudsContext.save();
                cloudsContext.clearRect(0, 0, cloudsCanvas.width, cloudsCanvas.height);

                deg += 1;
                // Center the needle on the canvas.
                cloudsContext.translate(cx, cy);
                cloudsContext.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180);
                cloudsContext.drawImage(cloud1, cloudCenter[0], cloudCenter[1]);

                cloudsContext.restore();
            }, 50);

        };

        cloud1.src = './img/cloud1.png';
 </script>
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: can't you just rotate the image by 90 degrees?

Comment: U mean the source image cloud1.png? Well, I can, but I take this as the last way, as I guess this can be solved in more elegant way, can't it?

Comment: well it seems like you're just making work for yourself if you could just rotate the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0 angle always points to the right so just create a cloud that is pre-rotated 90 degrees clock-wise (as if it was drawn in this place) - it should look like this:

[image: cloud]

Optionally you can pre-rotate using a secondary canvas to draw the non-rotated cloud into.

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/gSNbW/)**

You also need to do some other changes in your code:

- cloudCenter must be the start position to the right of the globe (ie. the location where it would be at 0 degree)
- translate back after rotation

Like this:

```
cloudsContext.translate(cx, cy);
cloudsContext.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180);
cloudsContext.translate(-cx, -cy);
cloudsContext.drawImage(cloud1, cloudCenter[0], cloudCenter[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other responders, I, too, think it’s more efficient to use a photo editor to pre-rotate your image 90 degrees.

But if you want to know how to do that programatically, here’s an example and a Fiddle.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YqBC2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var angle=0;
        var cx=150;
        var cy=150;
        var radius=50;
        var img90;

        var img=new Image()
        img.onload=function(){
            canvas.width=img.height;
            canvas.height=img.width;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
            ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
            ctx.restore();
            img90=new Image();
            img90.onload=function(){
                canvas.width=300;
                canvas.height=300;
                animate();
            }
            img90.src=canvas.toDataURL();
        }
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/cloud1.png";


        function draw(){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="orange";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(cx,cy);
            ctx.rotate(angle);
            ctx.drawImage(img90,radius+35-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
            ctx.restore();

        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            // Drawing code goes here
            angle+=Math.PI/360;
            draw();
        }


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```